# What are some of the sights to see in Budapest, Hungary?

Tags: sightseeing, hungary, budapest

I'm planning my first international trip out of the U.S. this fall to Budapest, Hungary. I'm visiting a very good friend who will be studying abroad.

What are some things to see in Budapest?

Comment: This question is pretty broad.  Check out this page about [how to ask questions](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask-beta) and especially the blog posts for the types of questions this SE site is for.

Comment: This is an excellent 'cultural guide' to Budapest: http://www.amazon.com/Budapest-Critical-Guide-Andras-Torok/dp/1873429312

Answer (score 18):

- Budapest is known for its thermal springs, as they're the largest in Europe, so you should try one of the many **baths**, such as the Gellert (very central location, but a bit touristy) or the wonderful [Szechenyi bath](http://www.szechenyibath.com/).
- The **market hall** is great for some local food, but also to buy souvenirs.
- The **synagogue** has some interesting and moving stories to tell.
- The **Buda castle** is also pretty impressive and you have a great view over the city and the river Danube, especially during dusk, when the **Chain Bridge** is illuminated.
- The **Houses of Parliament** are huge and very interesting if you're into architecture.
- Relax and have a drink and some cake in the **"Central" café**, which is a very nice Viennese style coffee house (Budapest was under Austrian rule for quite some time, so there's lots of influence throughout the city)

Enjoy your trip!

Comment: We visited Market Hall our first day there, and that was quite an experience. I did not have a chance to visit Houses of Parliament, as they were closed to Gov. business.

Answer (score 4):

Ruin bars are worth a look, and not just for a wild night out. They are night clubs but possibly not like you're used to. They are based in old derelict buildings houses, factories and office buildings that have been converted into clubs with makeshift furniture and sculptures from what ever was left lying around; cars cut in half and bath tubs as seats.

[Szimpla](http://www.szimpla.hu/budapest/home?Itemid=22) is a rather big one that I visited in 2010, but apparently there are loads you just need to ask a local for directions.

Comment: I forgot the House of Terror which is a museum covering the occupations and dictators from 1939 - 1990

Comment: I would just like to comment that I did visit Szimpla, and it was amazing!

Comment: Glad you liked it!